# Readability and efficiency, Which is better? Numpy, tuple, etc?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I'm working with xyz vectors a lot in my program. I'm using them enough that giving each one a variable (such as offset_x, offset_y, etc) is becoming tedious and cluttering code-wise. Now, I could put each set of x, y, and into tupples (such as offset = (x,y,z) ) , But I've found that doing stuff like offset[0] everywhere makes the code not quite as readable as I would like, Using a dict seems too inefficient. Numpy is another option, a lot of people have suggested it, but based on information found at [Poor numpy.cross() performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988091/poor-numpy-cross-performance) , Nunpy may not be quite as suitable for the short arrays I'm dealing with, and I don't have much margin for parts of my script slowing down, as some pieces are run several times a second. Is there anything out there that's both efficient and readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) if you're looking for a more readable tuple. Points are the example given in the docs.

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(11, y=22)     # instantiate with positional or keyword arguments
>>> p[0] + p[1]             # indexable like the plain tuple (11, 22)
33
>>> x, y = p                # unpack like a regular tuple
>>> x, y
(11, 22)
>>> p.x + p.y               # fields also accessible by name
33
>>> p                       # readable __repr__ with a name=value style
Point(x=11, y=22)
```

If you're interested in efficiency, checkout the [implementation](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/collections.py?view=markup). It uses `__slots__` and it's assembled using `exec` so it should be minimal overhead vs. a regular tuple.

Since it's coded in Python you could cut out a few of the possibly unnecessary methods like `__repr__`, `_asdict`, `_replace`, and `__getnewargs__` to reduce the footprint even more.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a wrapper over the tuple type? How much overhead does it incur?

Comment: And as for speed? I read up on Namedtuple, looking at both the docs and at http://pysnippet.blogspot.com/2010/01/named-tuple.html , and in the comment section, one person states that using a Namedtuple is 2-3 times slower. Sorry for grilling you, but one of my particularly important sections is run several times a second, and I don't have much wiggle room, performance wise. Aside from that, this looks like a great solution

Comment: It's written in Python, so it's going to be slower. NumPy is in C, as is the builtin `tuple`. If you want it to run faster and don't really _need_ NumPy, use PyPy instead of CPython, you'll get a major speedup.